# Find the order of the elements $Ha^2$, $Ha^3$, $Ha^4$, $Ha^5$ in G/H

Tags: abstract-algebra

Problem: If $G=<a>$, $\sigma<a>=24$ let $H=<a^6>$. Find the order of the elements $Ha^2$, $Ha^3$, $Ha^4$, $Ha^5$ in $G/H$.

What I've done so far:
$H=\{1,a^6,a^{12},a^{18}\}$,
$|G/H|=|G|/|K|=24/4=6$.

Is this right?:
$Ha^2$=H, so $2$
$Ha^3$=H, so $3$
and then how does $Ha^4$ and $Ha^5$ work?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the notation $\sigma<a>$ stand for? And do you mean $H=<a^6>$? If you do, why is $Ha^2=H$? We have $a^6a^2=a^8\notin H$, right?

Comment: $(Ha^2)(Ha^2)(Ha^2) = Ha^6=H$, so its order is 3. $Ha^2$ is not equal to $H$.

Comment: So the order for $Ha^3$ is 2?
What do I do with $Ha^4$ and $Ha^5$ since they don't go into 6.

Comment: Yes. Well they don't go into six, but where do they do go in?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. But, would the order of $Ha^5$ be 6 since the gcd(5,24)=1?

Comment: Well $(Ha^4)(Ha^4)(Ha^4)=Ha^{12}=H$, so that would be of order three, and $(Ha^5)^6=Ha^{30}=Ha^6=H$, so indeed as you said it has order $6$. I don't know how you tried to determine the order of the first two, but I hope you get how it can be done. Note that your options are limited anyways, since the order of any element has to divide the order of the group (assuming the group is finite, which it is here).

Answer (score 0):

We can find $(Ha)^k$ in one of two ways.

1. Inductively, by computing $(Ha)^2$, and then $(Ha)^2(Ha)$, and so on, until we reach $k$.

For example, let's compute $(Ha)^2 = \{h_1ah_2a: h_1h_2 \in H\}$.

Since $G$ is abelian, we can put the "$h$" 's first, and compute all possible $h_1h_2a^2$. The possible products $h_1h_2$ are:

$1\cdot 1 = 1\\1a^6 = a^6\\1a^{12} = a^{12}\\1a^{18} = a^{18}\\a^6 a^6 = a^{12}\\a^6a^{12} = a^{18}\\a^6a^{18} = 1\\a^{12}a^{12} = 1\\a^{12}a^{18} = a^6\\a^{18}a^{18} = a^{12}.$

So we wind up with just $4$ possible products: $\{1,a^6,a^{12},a^{18}\}$ (indeed, this is an example illustrating that $HH = H$). Now we multiply each possible product in $H$ by $a^2$, so we get:

$(Ha)^2 = \{a^2,a^8,a^{14},a^{20}\}$

This is the "long", and tedious way to go about things.

2. By using "coset multiplication" to realize $(Ha)^k = Ha^k$. Then we just find which coset $a^k$ is in. For reference, our cosets are:

$\{1,a^6,a^{12},a^{18}\} = H \\
\{a,a^7,a^{13},a^{19}\} = Ha\\ 
\{a^2,a^8,a^{14},a^{20}\} = Ha^2 \\ 
\{a^3,a^9,a^{15},a^{21}\} = Ha^3 \\
\{a^4,a^{10},a^{16},a^{22}\} = Ha^4 \\ 
\{a^5,a^{11},a^{17},a^{23}\} = Ha^5.$

Notice $Ha^6 = H$, so that the cosets after this "repeat" (the "name" for a coset isn't "unique", each coset has $4$ different "names"). This is by far the more efficient method.

So, for example, $(Ha)^2 = Ha^2 \neq H$ ($a^2$ isn't in $H$).

To find the order of $Ha^k$, we need to find the least positive power $m$ such that $a^{km} \in H$. Suppose $k = 2$. As we have seen $a^2 \not\in H$, so the order of $Ha^2$ is not one (it is not the identity of $G/H$).

$a^4 = (a^2)^2 \not \in H$, so the order of $Ha^2$ is not $2$.

$a^6 = (a^2)^3 \in H$, so the order of $Ha^2$ is $3$.